# Result variable assignment from a code block?

Tags: c#

coming from Scala to learn C# and I cant quite figure out how to do this in C#. Perhaps it's not supported? I got used to the neat idea of encapsulating small code block calculations within the larger code especially for variable initialization. Insights appreciated, perhaps there's a trick to mimic this. thank you!

```
var calc =        //invalid example wont compile
            {
                int x = 3; //x will not escape scope
            //do something, etc.
                return x; //assigned to calc as init 
            }
```

Comment: This is the same like `var calc = 3;` ;-)

Comment: it is assumed that there is more code between `x=3` and `return x`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure about Scala concept but AFAIK you can't do like that in c#. Instead, you can use inbuilt return type delegate called [Func](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in following way :

```
Func<int>  calc = () => { 
  int x = 3; //x will not escape scope
            //do something, etc.
                return x; //assigned to calc as init 
 };
```

Now, you can invoke above delegate by `calc()`.

Comment: Thank you, but the question is more about avoiding overhead than adding to it - I considered using anonymous inner functions in this way. Upvote for the example though..

Comment: I am confused with avoiding overhead when declaring variable. What overhead are you considering?

Comment: Hello, it was more about doing a compact series of calculations inside of a closed code block, and (all in one step) assign it to the variable during init. However, I've accepted C# doesnt really support this so I'm checking this as the most complete comparison answer for the thread. thank you again

Comment: Thank you for accepting. I am still not sure about the way you want, however you can check [creating Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) which gives a way to implement your logic for your private variable and expose it through property

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are after but you probably should be looking at lamba expressions:

```
var calc =  () => 
        {
            int x = 3; //x will not escape scope
        //do something, etc.
            return x; //assigned to calc as init 
        }
```

Comment: Upvoted Akash because I prefered the explicit type :P  *honorary comment*